# Slow Distribution System using Tensorflow

Tags: python, distributed, tensorflow

I am working on a project in Tensorflow with a large model, (One that won't fit on a 4 gb VGA).
Tl;dr: Running a part of the model on CPU and the other part on the GPU takes around 4 seconds/batch. We are making a distribution system that is supposed to work on 2-3 computers and we would like to distribute the tasks in a way that will ultimately speed up the process.

Details: 
With the lack of proper documentation (Or with other tutorials/guides) for distribution in tensorflow, we are facing a lot of problems. 
The best distribution system we were able to build was running: 1 ps and 1 worker (The worker has a part on the CPU and the second part on the GPU) , takes around 6 seconds/batch. Then we tried another setup: 1 ps, 2 workers (Each worker with 4gb VGA), and the best time we reached was around 7 seconds/batch and the last setup, was 2 ps on the same computer and 2 workers however each worker was running the entire model, so each were training batches differently.

```
args.cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": args.ps_hosts.split(","), "worker": args.worker_hosts.split(",")})
args.server = tf.train.Server(args.cluster,job_name=args.job_name,task_index=args.task_index)
if(args.job_name=="ps"):
    server.join()
else:
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % self.task_index,cluster=cluster)):

#Rest of code
.....
# Part where I divide the half on the cpu and half on the gpu:
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d/cpu:0" % self.task_index,cluster=cluster)):
            logger.write("First half gradient on  cpu")
            testGradient2 = tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars[len(tvars)/2:])
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d/gpu:0" % self.task_index,cluster=cluster)):
            logger.write("Second half gradient on gpu")
            testGradient1 = tf.gradients(self.cost, tvars[:len(tvars)/2])
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % self.task_index,cluster=cluster)):

        testGradient = testGradient1+testGradient2
....
#Supervisor part and configuration and session setup 
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(self.task_index == 0), init_op=tf.global_variables_initializer())
config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement = True)
self.sess = sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target,config=config)
```

As I said this code runs with around 6.5 seconds/batch, running on 2 ps (On the same computer), and 2 workers, is there any optimization or points that I am missing?